# Calling [table reloadData] removes table's position change from [uiview animatewithduration]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

There is a button that horizontally shifts my table.

```
- (void)togglePreferencePageVisibility:(id)sender {
     int translation = [self preferencesVisible] ? -PREFERENCE_TRANSLATION_HEIGHT : PREFERENCE_TRANSLATION_HEIGHT;
    //animate tableview down
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         _table.center = CGPointMake(_table.center.x, _table.center.y+translation);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     }];
}
```

When I call `[_table reloadData]`, the table reverts to its original position.  I tried manually readjusting the table position, like so

```
NSLog(@"before %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_table.frame));
    [_table reloadData];
    _table.frame = CGRectMake(initialTablePosition.x, initialTablePosition.y+PREFERENCE_TRANSLATION_HEIGHT, _table.frame.size.width, _table.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"after %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_table.frame));
```

but no luck.  Also the frame's have the same y position before and after.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also adjust the auto layout constraints using the NSLayoutConstraint class. You can add, remove or change the values of NSLayoutConstraints. This is a VERY common question on stack overflow right now, due to the change from iOS 7 to iOS 8.

If you do not adjust the layout constraints then the view will be repositioned back to its original location. `reloadData` redraws the UITableView which causes the view hierarchy to reexamine its positions e.t.c.

As an example of making a view with a width constraint narrower:

```
CGRect frame = myView.frame;
frame.size.width -= 100;
//Next line now needed in iOS 8
myWidthConstraint.constant -= 100;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [myView setFrame:frame];
}];
```

EDIT: moving back example:

```
CGRect frame = myView.frame;
    frame.size.width += 100;
    //Next line now needed in iOS 8
    myWidthConstraint.constant += 100;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [myView setFrame:frame];
    }];
```

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention is that the button that shifts the table position is a "toggle" button, so it also can shift the table back to its origin position. I just don't want the table to automatically shift back from reloadData.  Will this still work with autolayout?

Comment: You need to adjust the auto layout every time you reposition the view. So I'm assuming that if your table's in one place you move it to the other and vice versa. i.e. `if (isMoved) {// Move back}; else {// Move};` If this is the case then yes it will work but you need to redo the constraints see my edit for an example

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with iOS 8. When you use layout constraints, you shouldn't modify frames directly. It's been that way since constraints were introduced. This solution is not the correct way to do it; you shouldn't be setting frames at all, just modify the constraints.

Comment: I've come across people having problems just modifying the constraints and this method seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

When using auto layout, you should not set any frames. If you do, when the view needs to redraw itself, the frame will be reset to the frame defined by its constraints. You should add an IBOutlet to a constraint between your table view and the top (or bottom what ever works for your use) of its superview (I'll call it topCon in the example below).

```
- (void)togglePreferencePageVisibility:(id)sender {
     int translation = [self preferencesVisible] ? -PREFERENCE_TRANSLATION_HEIGHT : PREFERENCE_TRANSLATION_HEIGHT;
    //animate tableview down
    self.topCon.constant += translation; // this might need to be "-=" depending on whether your constraint is to the top or bottom
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     }];
}
```